# How do I Add A GIF/Video To Landing Screen Background In Xcode 6 using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, video, xcode6, gif

what is the most efficient way to add a GIF/Video to the background of the landing screen ( home screen or first view controller) of my app in Xcode? i.e apps like spotify, uber, insagram etc. Being that my app is universal, how would i make it fit accordingly?

Comment: Auto-layouting is solution for universal apps. However your question is quite unclear. Provide more detail.

Comment: what is video source? some url of playing from local storage?

Comment: no its a personal video, off my iPhone imported to my macbook @SaqibOmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the first screen that is displayed after your app is launched? If so: unfortunately you can't have dynamic content; you won't be able to use a gif/video.

That said, what you can do if you have some app-setup on background threads that will take some time anyway, or if you simply want the user to wait longer before interaction so that you can display the gif/video, you can make the static image match the first frame of the gif/video, and have your your entry point be a ViewController that displays the actual gif/video. Because this would delay the time to interaction, though, this would never be recommended.

As for making it fit: as of iOS 8 [Apple recommends using LaunchScreen.xib](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html). With it you can use Auto Layout to achieve universality.

To add a video you can use MPMoviePlayerController, AVPlayer, or if you're using SPritekit you can use an SKVideoNode.

EDIT (in response to follow-up comments):

An NSURL is a reference to a local or remote file. [This link](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle) will give you a decent overview. Just copy the movie in and follow that guide.

In addition to the MPMoviePlayerController solution Saqib Omer suggested, here's an alternative method that uses a UIView with an AVPlayerLayer. It has a button on top of the video as an example, since that's what you're looking for.

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Start with a generic UIView and add it to the ViewController view
        let myPlayerView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        myPlayerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        view.addSubview(myPlayerView)

        // Use a local or remote URL
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/76000/76740/iss030-e-6082_sdtv.mov") // See the note on NSURL above.

        // Make a player
        let myPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        myPlayer.play()

        // Make the AVPlayerLayer and add it to myPlayerView's layer
        let avLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: myPlayer)
        avLayer.frame = myPlayerView.bounds
        myPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(avLayer)

        // Make a button and add it to myPlayerView (you'd need to add an action, of course)
        let myButtonOrigin = CGPoint(x: myPlayerView.bounds.size.width / 3, y: myPlayerView.bounds.size.height / 2)
        let myButtonSize = CGSize(width: myPlayerView.bounds.size.width / 3, height: myPlayerView.bounds.size.height / 10)
        let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: myButtonOrigin, size: myButtonSize))
        myButton.setTitle("Press Me!", forState: .Normal)
        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        myPlayerView.addSubview(myButton)
    }
}
```

Comment: no not the launch image/screen, the actual first screen of interaction. the home screen I'm referring to. i.e apps like spotify, instagram, uber etc. they have videos running in the background while they have there sign uo buttons, login buttons etc accessible to the user

Comment: thanks it ran in the simulator really well, but i don't want the video played to rely on having internet access, i want it to play regardless of that which is why i want to create a path for a personal video of my own off my local disk, not a url off a site. that is still unclear to me. also i want it to play in a loop if possible

Comment: See the link about NSURL I put in my answer--you don't need to rely on the web, you can use a local file. For the button action and looping you should ask a new question (well, two new questions), or check for some tutorials online. The questions are supposed to focus on only one issue. You'll get there!

Answer (score 0):

For playing video add following code, declare class variable `var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!` . Than in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "YOUR_URL_FOR_VIDEO")



moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150)



 self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
  moviePlayer.fullscreen = true



moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
```

This will play video. But to fit it you need to add layout contraints. See [this](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/) link to add constraints pragmatically.

Comment: what if its a video from my personal collection off my iPhone imported into my mac, will the url be "nil"? and is MPMoviePlayer in the swift library already? @saqib omer

Comment: Here is a good tutorial of what you want to have. https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2

Answer (score 0):

```
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load the video from the app bundle.
        let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("video", withExtension: "mp4")!

        // Create and configure the movie player.
        self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)

        self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill

        self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view .insertSubview(self.moviePlayer.view, atIndex: 0)

        self.moviePlayer.play()

        // Loop video.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loopVideo", name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: self.moviePlayer)
    }

    func loopVideo() {
        self.moviePlayer.play()
    }
```

https://medium.com/@kschaller/ios-video-backgrounds-6eead788f190#.2fhxmc2da